# globalize3 and easy_globalize3_accessors validation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, localization, internationalization, globalize3

I'm using gems: globalize3 and easy_globalize3_accessors.
I have a problem with validations. For example, I have Post model:

```
class Post
  translates :title, :content
  globalize_accessors :locales => [:en, :ru], :attributes => [:title, :content]
  validates :title, :content, :presence => true
end
```

and form:

```
= form_for @post do |f|
  -I18n.available_locales.each do |locale|
    = f.text_field "title_#{locale}"
    = f.text_area "content_#{locale}"
```

it looks like in view (if I18n.locale = :ru):

```
<form action="/ru/posts" method="post">
  <input id="post_title_ru" name="post[title_ru]" type="text" />
  <textarea cols="40" id="post_content_ru" name="vision[content_ru]"></textarea>

  <input id="post_title_en" name="post[title_en]" type="text" />
  <textarea cols="40" id="post_content_en" name="vision[content_en]"></textarea>

  <input name="commit" type="submit" value="Создать Видение" />
</form>
```

If I fill in the fields only in Russian, the validation passes, if I wanted to post was in English only, and fill only the English field (when I18n.locale = :ru), the validation fails

```
Title can't be blank
Content can't be blank
```

As I understand it, there is a problem in the attributes, validation checks only the first attributes :title_ru and :content_ru. And to the rest of attributes (:content_en and :title_en) check does not reach.

how to make a second data validator to check if the validation of the first group of attributes is not passed?

thanks in advance

Comment: what about `validates :title_ru, :content, :presence => true`and `validates :title_en, :content, :presence => true`

Comment: if  i want to post only :title_en and :content_en - validation is failed

Comment: create a custom validator checking that at least one is set. Need help?

Comment: I would be very grateful for the help. I tried to create a validator (and tried with :unless option), but my knowledge is probably not enough (

Comment: if my snwer fits, don't forget to accept it please

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
validate :titles_validation

def titles_validation
  errors.add(:base, "your message") if [title_ru, title_en].all? { |value| value.blank? }
end
```

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that globalize3 is validating the title for *whatever locale you are currently in*. If you want to validate for *every* locale (and not just the *current* locale), you have to explicitly add validators for the attribute in each locale (as  @apneadiving pointed out).

You should be able to generate these validators automatically by cycling through `I18n.available_locales`:

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  I18n.available_locales.each do |locale|
    validates :"title_#{locale}", :presence => true
  end

  ...

end
```

Comment: that's what comments are made for